# php date can't get 24 digit time hour

Tags: php, date

I'm using date function `$now=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`  in php 5.6.30, 
The browser output is `string(19) "2017-04-21 02:54:54"`,That's abnormal.

php.ini set is `date.timezone = PRC`

Centos 7 system time:

`[root@localhost sync]# date
Fri Apr 21 14:53:20 CST 2017`

While I was installed the PHP 7.0.16 in the same system, php.ini has the same config, but the date output normal in date function(is 24 digit time). 
Why happen this and how to let the date normal working.

Comment: **$now=date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); in php 5.6.30, The browser output is string(19) "2017-04-21 02:54:54",That's abnormal.** why ?

Comment: Its PM in my local , so Its should be "2017-04-21 14:54:54"

Comment: Use  `date.timezone = Asia/Shanghai`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this below code for date timezone

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Shanghai');
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a timezone issue.

In your php.ini, you have the timezone `PRC` (China) set, but your system time output gives the time in `CST` (Amerika).
In other words:
Your PHP code does actually give you the 24-hour format, but in a different timezone, **where it is in fact 02:54:54**

If you need to get the time in a different timezone (like `UTC`), you can set it like that:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

If you need a different local timezone, you can read about the possible values in the [list of supported timezones in the PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm add the code to php.ini `date.timezone = Asia/Shanghai`,
and install chrony and start it to synchronized. It works.

Comment: Then accept an answer as correct one. Don't answer it yourself